# Masonite Invalid CSRF token

Tags: python, django, masonite

Invalid CSRF Token

raise InvalidCSRFToken("Invalid CSRF Token")

After running the command "**python craft serve**" it is showing this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Go to browser> right click> inspect > Application > cookies > localhost > delete csrf token.

It will work.